# Record not in unsubscribe data view when the LogUnsubEvent API request is made

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, data-views, unsubscribe

I have added a subscriber via the update API with a status of "Active" to the all subscribers list, and then the logunsubevent request is made for that subscriber.

After that, I looked for this subscriberkey in the _unsubscribe data view but it was not showing up.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are likely missing a jobId in your LogUnsubEvent.

See here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call.html

> The Job Context is defined by the JobID, ListID and BatchID parameters. These values are used to determine which Job the UnsubEvent is tracked against. The subscriber is also unsubscribed from the List that the Job was sent to. You don't need to supply all three values. The system looks up any missing values using the following rules:

> If the JobID is supplied, we can lookup a missing ListID and/or BatchID.
> If the ListID is supplied, we can lookup a missing JobID and/or BatchID.
> If the JobID is missing, we use the most recent JobID that the subscriber was sent to.
> This may not be the Job that the Subscriber is acting upon.
> If only the BatchID is supplied, we cannot lookup the remaining information and the job context is not defined.

> *If the job context cannot be established because you did not supply any of these parameters or only supplied the BatchID, the UnsubEvent is not created*. The subscriber is also *Master Unsubscribed from the system* instead of being unsubscribed from a particular list. Remove the ListID to *address the All Subscribers list* in an account.

What's marked in italics is exactly what you are seeing. The status on all subscribers changes but the event in the unsub data view is not performed.

If you cannot establish a jobid - check what ListId your all subscribers has, and use that as ListId. It will then be both unsubscribed on All Subs AND have an event in the data view.

Comment: Thank you for the response. There is no email sent out for that subscriber yet and when I passed list ID in the request the response shows below error: <Results>
                <StatusCode>Error</StatusCode>
                <StatusMessage>Subscriber not found on the specified send</StatusMessage>
                <ErrorCode>400</ErrorCode>
            </Results>                                                                                                                   So the subscriber key that is being passed to the request will always have email go out for unsubevent to be created.

Comment: If you don't have a jobid why do you expect this to write to the unsubscribe data view? @Akhila

Comment: Thanks I was testing this without sending an email. After testing with subscriberkey's jobID, I am able to see the data in the data view.